# Introduce delay in libgdx Animation

Tags: java, libgdx

I am using libgdx on a little game and I have a little animation on my menu screen. I have used Animation() class and gave it a list of 20 sprites. The animation duration is 2 seconds. What I want is to make this animation repeat each 4 seconds. So I need a way to introduce delay between repetitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if the Animation class has native support for delays like this, but you can always just keep track of elapsed time yourself and restart the animation after the elapsed time passes 4 seconds.  For details see: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/25001/waiting-specific-time-to-increase-sound-libgdx

Comment: This is the approach I have already taken. I wanted to know if there was a cleaner way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can always try the delay() action from the

```
import static com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.actions.Actions.delay;
```

here's how I use it internally in an Actor class, together with some other actions. They're pretty cool and low on memory usage.

```
this.addAction(sequence(moveBy(0, 10, 0.1f), moveBy(0, -10, 0.1f),delay(0.75f),run(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run () {
                    Gdx.app.log("NOTICE", " Notice deleted!");     
                    disappear();
            }})));
```